# Why is "no" used in a phrase like "this is no big deal" instead of "not"?

Tags: american-english

The following is the full sentence:

> One could argue, convincingly, that this is no big deal and that I'm just a whiner.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the *New Oxford American English* reports, *no* (used as adjective) means *not any*.

> There is no excuse.
>   No two plants are alike.

Comment: So "not any two plants are alike"?

Comment: @Shinto, it is awkward, but not ungrammatical, at least to me. You can’t presume that any word can be replaced by a dictionary definition and have the result always be perfectly normal-sounding.

Comment: @nohat: I don't think "not any two plants are alike" is understandable, let alone grammatical. My guess is that "no two .. alike" is a construction on its own. There is no "no three" construction or similar.

Comment: @Shinto: why wouldn't there be no "no three" constructions? What about: *"What is the probability that no three consecutive letters are alike"*; or: *"In the Bengali alphabet no three letters are alike in sound except the three sibilants"* [see this wiki article](http://veda.wikidot.com/kshama); or even the ominous: *"no five fingers are alike"* [see Google](http://www.google.nl/search?q=%22no+five+fingers+are+alike%22). They all fit the same adjective use of *"no"* in the meaning of *"not any"*.

Comment: @Abel: OK I concede that there can be "no three" constructions but why you want to force this to mean "not any" I have no idea.